# How to use re.sub to remove numbers

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove the numbers from my string, but keep the numbers that are in the middle. Right now my output for the code below is:

> "This is a test numbers at end or beginning of a word should be deleted but not ones in the middle."

but I want it to be:

> "This is a test numbers at end or beginning of a word should be deleted but not ones in the midd3le."

How should I do this?

```
String = "This is a test numbers33 at end or 333beginning of a word should be deleted but not ones in the midd3le."

s = re.sub("[\d]", "", String)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this pattern:

```
String = "This is a test numbers33 at end or 333beginning of a word should be deleted but not ones in the midd3le."

s = re.sub(r"\b\d+|\d+\b", "", String)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4NrLLB/1)